# ROS beginner tutorials:Writing Simple Service and Client (C++) - need explanation

Tags: ros, c++, beginner-tutorials, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the **ROS beginner tutorials** and currently doing **14.Writing Simple Service and Client (C++)** (http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29)

In **Section 1.2 Writing the Client Node**, the following lines of code have not been explained:

```
   8   if (argc != 3)
   9   {
  10     ROS_INFO("usage: add_two_ints_client X Y");
  11     return 1;
  12   }
```

Can anyone tell me why this comparison is made? Thanks in advance.

P.S.I'm using ROS groovy on Ubuntu 12.10. Following catkin tutorials.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61006/ros-beginner-tutorials:writing-simple-service-and-client-(c++)---need-explanation/) by [Maheshwar Venkat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4623/maheshwar-venkat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

`argc` refers to total number of arguments that can be passed to a node. In your case, when you run `rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_client 5 6`, you enter three arguments add_two_ints_client(argv[0]),5(argv[1]) and 6(argv[2]). For the node add_two_ints to function properly second and third arguments, the integers, are required along with node name. The comparison, if (argc != 3) is made to check if the required number of arguments needed to run the client are obtained. If you use `rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_client 5` (argc = 2)or `rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_client 5 6 7` ((argc = 4),  `usage: add_two_ints_client X Y will appear`.

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maheshwar Venkat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4623/maheshwar-venkat/) on 2013-04-17**:
understood clearly. thank you.!